# Apply box-shadow on some table columns

Tags: css

I'm trying to put some `box-shadow` on some *columns group* of my html table but I'm getting an overlay of box-shadow on every `<td>`. (In my context, I can't split my table)

html :

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="transparent"></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="transparent"></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td class="transparent"></td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css :

```css
table {
  margin: 50px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td:not(.transparent) {
  padding: 2em;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 24px rgba(128, 128, 128, .15);
}
td.transparent {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

Actual look :

[image: actual_look]

Wanted look :

[image: wanted_look]

Comment: It is required to add your code that you have tried so that we can find and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of a hack but it ends up similar to what you want.

I added a `span` to each `td`.

The logic is to have a `:before` element to cover the inner `td` space with white (`background`). The `span` meant to bring the text one layer ahead.

So the layers are

- Shadow (`td`) `z-index: 0`

  - White cover (`:before`) `z-index: 1`

    - Text (`span`) `z-index: 2`

```css
table {
  margin: 50px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  padding: 2em;
  position: relative;
}

td:not(.transparent) {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 24px rgba(128, 128, 128, .15);
}

td:not(.transparent):before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
}

td:not(.transparent) span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

td.transparent {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td class="transparent"></td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td class="transparent"></td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td class="transparent"></td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span>test</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Love you ! Thanks :)